# different title, keyword and description in every page's 

Tags: php, title, keyword

How can I add a different title, keyword and description in every page's `<head>` of my simple php website dynamically?

I have included file header.php in all of my pages, how can i know in what page the user in?

For example, I have php files register.php, and login.php, and I need different titles, keywords and descriptions.

I do not want use the `$_GET` method.

Thanks!

Comment: If you have lots of files you should create a database and retrieve the values from there, otherwise just do it manually.

Answer (score 7):

Set variables at the top of each page that will be read by `header.php`.  Then insert the values of the variables in the right places in `header.php`.  Here is an example:

register.php:

```
<?php
    $title = "Registration";
    $keywords = "Register, login";
    $description = "Page for user registration";

    include('header.php');
?>
```

header.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $keywords; ?>" />
        <meta name="description" content="<?php echo $description; ?>" />
        <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
    </head>
    <body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the output inside a function (within your header.php) and insert its parameters at appropriate places into the markup.

```
function html_header($title = "Default") {
    ?><!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title><?php echo $title ?></title>
    </head>
    …
    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

for example the `$page` variable is your page name:

```
<?php
 switch($page) 
  {
    case 'home':
     $title = 'title';
     $keyword = 'some keywords..';
     $desc = 'description';
    break;
    case 'download':
     $title = 'title';
     $keyword = 'some keywords..';
     $desc = 'description';
    break;
    case 'contact':
     $title = 'title';
     $keyword = 'some keywords..';
     $desc = 'description';
    break;
  }

if(isset($title))
{
   ?>
 <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
 <meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $keyword; ?>" />
 <meta name="description" content="<?php echo $desc; ?>" />
 <?php
}
else
{
   ?>
 <title>default</title>
 <meta name="keywords" content="default" />
 <meta name="description" content="default" />
 <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Why not immediately set the needed variables, instead of using `$page` and a huge `switch … case`?